# Como dividir uma tabela e manter os registros em PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Em um sistema de gestão patrimonial, eu tenho uma tabela chamada `patrimonios_cedidos` que possui os campos:

```sql
patrimonios_cedidos:
id integer (pk)
data_cedencia date
data_retorno date
responsavel_id bigint (fk)
responsavel_destino_id bigint (fk)
localizacao_inicial_id bigint (fk)
localizacao_destino_id bigint (fk)
patrimonio_id bigint (fk)
```

O problema é que essa tabela possui uma relação 1 para 1 com a tabela `patrimonio`, e toda vez que é gerado uma nova cedência, uma nova linha é criado na tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` para cada patrimônio. Porém, agora, eu preciso mudar isso para que em uma única cedência eu possa ter vários patrimônios.

O que eu resolvi fazer foi criar uma nova tabela chamada `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`, afim de salvar os dados da cedência. Essa nova tabela possui os campos:

```sql
patrimonios_cedidos_itens:
id integer (pk)
patrimonio_id bigint (fk)
patrimonio_cedido_id bigint (fk)
localizacao_inicial_id bigint (fk)
```

Essa nova tabela, `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`, vai servir para o registro da cedência, possuindo os dados como qual patrimônio foi cedido e de onde veio (para onde deve voltar quando o período da cedência acabar). Depois disso eu precisaria de uma nova tabela de `patrimonios_cedidos`:

```sql
temporary_patrimonios_cedidos:
id integer (pk)
data_cedencia date
data_retorno date
responsavel_id bigint (fk)
responsavel_destino_id bigint (fk)
localizacao_destino_id bigint (fk)
```

Agora eu precisaria pegar minha tabela, `patrimonios_cedidos`, e jogar todas as linhas para as tabelas `temporary_patrimonios_cedidos` e `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`. Eu precisaria fazer um `loop` passando em todos os dados de `patrimonios_cedidos`, colocar nas respectivas tabelas, pegar o `id` da `temporary_patrimonios_cedidos` e colocar no `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`. Pelo menos é o que estou tentando, mas não sei como fazer isso. Alguns dados das tabelas e as tabelas de `localizacao`, `responsavel` e `patrimonio` eu não coloquei aqui porque acredito não ser necessário, porém caso esclareça melhor minha situação eu posso editar a pergunta colocando o que for necessário.

**Edit:**
Algo que não havia esclarecido, mas a tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` será substituída por `temporary_patrimonios_cedidos` e `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`. Após passar os dados da tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` para as outras tabelas, a mesma será dropada e a `temporary_patrimonios_cedidos` será renomeada para `patrimonios_cedidos`. A relação da nova tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` com a `patrimonios_cedidos_itens` será pela `fk` na tabela `patrimonios_cedidos_itens`: `patrimonio_cedido_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o método mais prático para obter esse resultado seria fazendo 2 *queries*, uma para cada tabela "partilhada". Para isso é simples, basta você usar o `INSERT` — com os campos pertinentes — concatenado ao retorno do `SELECT` da tabela original `patrimonios_cedidos`.

Ficaria assim:

```
--Para copiar os dados relevantes à tabela 'patrimonios_cedidos_itens'
INSERT INTO patrimonios_cedidos_itens(patrimonio_id, patrimonio_cedido_id, localizacao_inicial_id) SELECT patrimonio_id, id, localizacao_inicial_id FROM patrimonios_cedidos;

--Para copiar os dados relevantes à tabela 'temporary_patrimonios_cedidos'
INSERT INTO temporary_patrimonios_cedidos(data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id) SELECT data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id FROM patrimonios_cedidos;
```

Adicionalmente, outra coisa que recomendaria para isso funcionar sem problemas é declarar a chave primária de cada uma das tabelas como tipo [SERIAL em vez de INTEGER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38803140/12195738) — isso a não ser que a versão do seu PostgreSQL seja maior ou igual a 10, nesse caso o mais recomendado seria [IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017032/12195738) — para evitar erros ao omitir o campo `id` durante criação de novos registros.

EDIT: Caso exista a possibilidade de ocorrerem problemas de integridade entre as cedências da tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` e `temporary_patrimonios_cedidos` ao utilizar a chave estrangeira `patrimonio_cedido_id`  baseado no `id` da tabela original, ao meu ver existem 2 soluções:

- Adicionar a coluna `id` para ficar equivalente entre as tabelas nova e antiga

```
INSERT INTO temporary_patrimonios_cedidos(id, data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id) SELECT id, data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id FROM patrimonios_cedidos;
```

- Fazer um `JOIN` entre as tabelas nova e antiga para obter o `id` (mais limpo)

```
--Invertendo a ordem dos INSERTs originais

INSERT INTO temporary_patrimonios_cedidos(data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id) SELECT data_cedencia, data_retorno, responsavel_id, responsavel_destino_id, localizacao_destino_id FROM patrimonios_cedidos;

INSERT INTO patrimonios_cedidos_itens(patrimonio_id, patrimonio_cedido_id, localizacao_inicial_id) SELECT orig.patrimonio_id, ced.id, orig.localizacao_inicial_id FROM patrimonios_cedidos AS orig INNER JOIN temporary_patrimonios_cedidos AS ced ON ced.data_cedencia = orig.data_cedencia AND ced.data_retorno = orig.data_retorno AND ced.responsavel_id = orig.responsavel_id AND ced.responsavel_destino_id = orig.responsavel_destino_id AND ced.localizacao_destino_id = orig.localizacao_destino_id;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Rfroes87. Sobre a questão das `primary key`, estou usando sim `SERIAL`, mas por algum motivo, ao abrir as propriedades da tabela mostra que a coluna é `INTEGER`, então optei por colocar assim; e também acabei não deixando tão claro, mas a tabela `patrimonio_cedido` será substituída pelas outras duas, sendo que depois de passar todos os dados para as outras tabelas, a tabela `patrimonio_cedido` seria dropada e a temporaria seria renomeada para `patrimonios_cedidos`. Com isso, a tabela `patrimonios_cedidos_itens` receberia na fk o id da nova tabela `patrimonios_cedidos`.

Comment: @LuizFelipeRodrigues Você diz que nesse caso os `id`s que seriam gerados na **nova** tabela `patrimonios_cedidos` poderiam ser incompatíveis com os da tabela original?

Comment: No caso de a tabela original começar com o id 2, por exemplo, sim. Acredito que seria melhor "resetar" os `id`s, por assim dizer, já que se não estiver na ordem acredito que o `SERIAL`, na nova tabela, vai gerar erro por tentar adicionar dados com um id que já existe. Mas se houver um jeito de evitar este problema seria melhor.

Comment: Olá @Rfroes87 optei por usar a primeira opção. Só fiz uma edição na sua resposta porque o nome do campo é `data_cedencia`, seria a data que o bem foi emprestado; credência seria outra coisa kkkk